# How to get Image extention and name when url doesnot have this . (PHP)

Tags: php, image

I have an URL in following format

```
www.domain.com/image.php?id=123&idlocation=987&number=01
```

It has image that has to be downloaded I use following function to download

```
$codigo =  file_get_contents($url);
```

So now How I can get the exteion of the image file using `$codigo`

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you just want to get `php` from your url ?

Comment: @Rizier123 There is an image when you do file_get_contents() in that url , SO now in $codigo it will have image details in coded form , My problem is to get the name and extention of the image from $codigo

Answer (score -1):

```
$path_parts = pathinfo('/www/htdocs/inc/lib.inc.php');

echo $path_parts['dirname'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['basename'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['extension'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['filename'], "\n"; // since PHP 5.2.0
```

kindly refer this link to get file info

http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Comment: it will not work for the scenario I have iven it will give .php as out put for extention but i have to get the extention of the image that is being downloaded from the url